# Behavior of log_loss in scikit learn vis-à-vis numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, precision

I tried to compute the log loss using log_loss that's implemented in scikit learn. First I used

```
log_loss(y_test,y_pred_NN_2L_ReLu)
```

And I got this warnning

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:2240: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log loss = -(transformed_labels * np.log(y_pred)).sum(axis=1) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:2240: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply loss = -(transformed_labels * np.log(y_pred)).sum(axis=1)
```

and a nan value.

Now, when I used `log_loss(y_test,y_pred_NN_2L_ReLu.astype(float))`

I got a real value

Can anyone explain why log_loss is behaving differently ? Thank you for your help